# Why does IntelliJ IDEA offer css animation names?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

If you write `@keyframes` in a css file in IntelliJ IDEA it suggests you animation names like blink, dance, fadein, fadeout etc.

Is it just a name suggestion function? Can I get the implementations behind these names somehow from IDEA? I guess you have the same functionality in Webstorm too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebStorm and IDEA are collecting all `@keyframe` names in the project during indexing. All these names are suggested in completion when you write `@keyframes` or `animation-name:`.

Showing an implementation behind a suggested name is not implemented yet (WebStorm 2016.3.3). I've filed a feature request about it, you may want to vote for it to get updates on its progress: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25641